# How can you configure Solaris 9 to automatically start Synergy or an X-dependent application at startup?

Tags: solaris, system-administration

How does one configure a Solaris 9 machine to automatically start Synergy(synergy2.sourceforge.net) or any other X-dependent application at startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do the ["Autostarting" instructions](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/autostart.html) for Synergy not apply to your setup? If you are using CDE, that is, dtlogin is providing the graphical login, you'll find the corresponding files in `/usr/dt/config/`. Be sure to read `/usr/dt/config/Xconfig` for the instructions to modify the configuration files properly. (Just checked this on Solaris 10.)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to add it to the appropriate rc directory, and make the script name come after starting X lexicographically.  I don't have an S9 system to look at right now, but I *think* you'll want to add it to the RC for runlevel 3, (vice 4, thanks Martin) and you should be good if you name it anywhere in the 90's.

Oh, and [BigAdmin](http://bigadmin.sun.com) will have a lot of handy howtos for this kind of thing.

Comment: You probably want run level 3 (multi-user + networking). Run level 4 is pretty funky (not a default).

Comment: It's not what you don't know that hurts you, it what you think you know that ain't so.